# querying null fields using pyorient OGM

Tags: python, null, pyorient

I'm trying to use the OGM from pyorient to match records which have nulls in some of their fields.

I managed to get most things working by looking through the unit tests on GitHub but I couldn't find any examples there or in the docs. I also couldn't see any issues on GitHub, so I guess I'm just approaching it the wrong way.

pyOrient version : 1.5.5

python version : 3.6.3

OrientDB version : 2.2.31

I've put an end to end set up below to highlight the problem, which is with the final query.

```
from pyorient.ogm import Graph, Config, declarative
from pyorient.ogm.property import (String, Integer)
ogm_config = Config.from_url("localhost/ogm_test", "root", "root", initial_drop = True)
g = Graph(ogm_config)
Node = declarative.declarative_node()

class table_a(Node):
    element_plural = 'table_a'
    column_1 = String()
    column_2 = Integer()
g.create_all(Node.registry)

db_data = [
    {"column_1":"Test 1", "column_2" : 1},
    {"column_1":"Test 1"},
    {"column_1":"Test 2", "column_2" : 1},
    {"column_1":"Test 2", "column_2" : None},
    ]

for data in db_data:
    res = g.table_a.create(**data)

query_res = g.table_a.query(**db_data[0]).all()
print(len(query_res)) # expected 1 got 1 i.e. (db_data[0])

query_res = g.table_a.query(**db_data[1]).all()
print(len(query_res)) # expected 2 got 2 i.e. (db_data[0] and db_data[1])

query_res = g.table_a.query(**db_data[2]).all()
print(len(query_res)) # expected 1 got 1 i.e. (db_data[2])

query_res = g.table_a.query(**db_data[3]).all()
print(len(query_res)) # expected 1 got 0 ??????? I expected db_data[3]
```

Many thanks,

Graham

Comment: Seems to be a bug. query.py:build_wheres() returns 'column_1 = "Test 2" and column_2=null', but I think it ought to return 'column_1 = "Test 2" and column_2 IS null'. Will raise an issue in Github for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a defect, as per my comment. Have raised an issue on GitHub.

Issue #262: OGM: NULL fields not queried correctly